# Use `@Ignore` field in `@Query` result using Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have two simple `location` and `houses` tables.
I'd like to be able to fetch a `location` with all it's relevant information, and also add the `house` count to that query. The `houseCount` field is marked `@Ignored` since I don't want this saved. Room however can't seem to use the field for returning the data from a query like it would for any other class specified as a return object type for a query.

My field:

```
@Ignore
@ColumnInfo(name = EXTRA_COLUMN_LOCATION_HOUSE_COUNT)
public int houseCount;
```

My location constructor:

```
public Location(long id, String name, LatLng location, long defaultRent, Date synced, int houseCount) {...}
```

My query:

```
SELECT locations.*, COUNT(DISTINCT houses.id) AS house_count FROM locations, houses WHERE locations.id = :id AND houses.location_id = :id
```

The warning:

```
Warning:(37, 14) The query returns some columns [house_count] which are not use by ug.karuhanga.logrealty.Models.Entities.Location. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: id, name, location, default_rent, synced, house_count. Fields in ug.karuhanga.logrealty.Models.Entities.Location: id, name, location, default_rent, synced.
```

and error:

```
Error:(33, 8) error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
Location(long,java.lang.String,ug.karuhanga.logrealty.Utils.LocationUtils.LatLng,long,java.util.Date,int) : [id : id, name : name, location : location, defaultRent : defaultRent, synced : synced, houseCount : null]
```

Comment: Did you try adding a empty public constructor for `Location` class? Try adding it and I'm pretty sure your error will go away. 
Let me know if that works

Comment: Hey, no sorry I'd taken the easier way out and done away with the `@Ignore`. Let me try this though.

Comment: I have this same issue. I don't want to write the field but I do want to read it. I'd prefer not to use separate objects for querying and inserting but that's the only solution I can think of right now.

Comment: @gMale This seems like the approach the designers had in mind. +1

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this for workaround with @Ignore in room db.
[Room database build errors for @Ignore annotation](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/421)

Comment: This saved my life. The official documentation is wrong and should be updated.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The op wants to have a 'read-only' / dynamic/computed field which cannot be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, this worked for me:

**1. Add `@JvmOverloads` to your data class like this:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student @JvmOverloads constructor(
    ...
)
```

**2. Place the `@PrimaryKey` field at the end of your constructor like this:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student @JvmOverloads constructor(    
    var name: String,            
    var age: Int,                 
    var gpa: Double,
    var isSingle: Boolean,

    @Ignore                            
    var isSelected: Boolean = false,      

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)        //must be placed at the end!!
    var id: Long = 0                        
)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe very late as this post was done back in 2020 but as i search a lot for a solution. finally found this post but could not translate this to java so had to come up with my own solution.
There are probebly better solutions but i could not find them so below my solution in the hope it will help somebody else.

I wanted to do this.

```
@Query("SELECT tableA.*, " +
       "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB WHERE tableB.Id = tableA.Id) AS Counter " +
       "FROM tableA")
LiveData<List<MyObject>> getmyObjectLiveData();
```

For this i had an MyObject class with:

```
@Ignore
Counter
```

That resulted in the same warning as above.
In the end i solved it by creating a second object "MyObject2" that has the same fields as the "MyObject" class but no without any database refs (@Entity, @PrimaryKey, @NonNull and @Ignore all removed). added the Counter-field to the constructor and changed my live update query the result to "MyObject2".
Of course had to change a number of classes as by data was used by a recyclerview so, not only change the DAO but also the repository, the viewmodel and the adapter to work with this MyObject2-class But is works great without any error's/warning's

I added an extra public method to the MyObject2-class to easly retrieve a MyObject-class version because in the end i still need to original MyObject to handle the inserts and updates. and MyObject is basicly a subset of the fields of MyObject2